# Pattern matching and floating point representation

Tags: haskell

I'm doing a problem involving using numeric methods to solve a differential equation, and thought this might be a good opportunity to learn some basic Haskell. I have the following recurrence relation:

[image: recurrence relation]

and the initial condition `u(x, 0) = x^2`. I translated these into Haskell like so (putting in appropriate values for a,b,c,h and k from the specific problem, and noting that u_ij is defined as `u(i*h, j*k)`):

```
u :: (Floating a, Eq a) => a -> a -> a
u x 0 = x*x
u x t = a*k / b*h * (u (x-h) (t-k)) 
      + (1 - (3*k/2*h))*(u x (t-k)) 
      + k/b * cos x
    where 
        a = 3
        b = 2
        k = 0.1
        h = 0.2

main = putStrLn (show (u 1 0.5))
```

This appears to run indefinitely. My best guess as to why is that floating point representation means the `u x 0` pattern never actually matches. The way I'm used to dealing with this in other languages is to check if the absolute difference between the values is within some suitable epsilon, but this doesn't appear to be available for pattern matching. So it seems that floating point and pattern matching are fundamentally incompatible. Is this the likely problem, and if so, is there a canonical way to avoid one or the other in a situation like this?

Comment: ...`j` will never be 0 if it starts at 0.5, as it always decreases by 1 in the translated recurrence relation (so it will be 0.5 -> -0.5 -> -1.5...). I think `u` is supposed to be indexed by the natural numbers, not the real numbers?

Comment: Pattern matching in floating point is bogus. You probably just shouldn't do that.

Comment: @Michael that was a mistake as you suspect. `u_ij` in the recurrence is defined as `u(i*h, j*k)`, so that i and j are integers, but u is defined for real x and t. I've fixed that and updated the code in the question, but it shows the same problem.

Comment: @dfeuer I thought that might be the case, but what can I do instead?

Comment: @lvc nobody forces you do use pattern matching everywhere - you can do the same as you used to: don match on the second parameter but use it to calculate you difference to epsilon and then use `if ... then ... else ...` ;) (you could use guards too - but IMO you should start by getting the algorithm to work before you get fancy if you just started with the language - focus on one thing: the lang. or the algorithm first)

Comment: @Carsten guards did the trick; thanks for the pointer. It honestly never occurred to me to use an `if` statement (or even look into whether Haskell has them); I looked into Haskell for this problem exactly because of how directly the algebra translates into code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the solution was to read a little further into the tutorial and use *guards* instead of pattern matching; they make checking against an epsilon quite trivial:

```
u :: (Floating a, Ord a) => a -> a -> a
u x t 
    | abs t <= 0.1 = x*x
    | otherwise =  a*k / b*h * (u (x-h) (t-k))
                   + (1 - (3*k/2*h))*(u x (t-k))
                   + k/b * cos x
      where
          a = 3
          b = 2
          k = 0.1
          h = 0.2

main = putStrLn (show (u 1 0.5))
```

Gives an answer very quickly.